# How do I prevent res.sendFile('/404.html') from redirecting the current path to /404.html?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

I am using `express 4.x` to handle an error:

```
try {
  // ... normal logic
} catch (error) {
  // error logic
  return res.status(404).sendFile('/404.html');
}
```

When the user visits a non-existed path, like https://example.com/not-exist

I want the user to stay on that path `/not-exist`.

But it's not happening. Instead, the browser redirects me to `/404.html`, so what's in the address bar is: https://example.com/404.html

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the root when calling sendFile. This code works for me:

```
try {
  // ... normal logic
} catch (error) {
  // error logic
  return res.status(404).sendFile(process.cwd()+'/404.html');
}
```

However, if you want a shorter but deprecated approach, you can use sendfile.

```
try {
  // ... normal logic
} catch (error) {
  // error logic
  return res.status(404).sendfile('./404.html');
}
```

The difference between the non-deprecated and deprecated approach is the capitalisation of file. I recommend you only use sendFile.

Comment: Tried both ways, still changing my path.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Good luck I guess, that's all the errors I found.

Answer (score 0):

Try __dirname

```
try {
  // ... normal logic
} catch (error) {
  // error logic
  return res.status(404).sendFile(path.join('__dirname', '404.html'));
}
```